# population select option using json_encode

Tags: jquery, json

Can someone help me figure out why the json array I have is not population my select drop down? The array prints fine (name:value) and I have tried different ways (.post .getJSON) to fill the select fields. See my code below...

PHP

```
$q = "select Site_ID, FirstName, LastName from ClientInfo";
$sql = mysql_query($q);
$data = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql, true)){
    $data[] = $row; 
};
echo json_encode($data);
```

This is what it prints on webpage:

```
[{"Site_ID":"10000001","FirstName":"drew","LastName":"0"},     {"Site_ID":"10000002","FirstName":"hello","LastName":"0"},{"Site_ID":"10000003","FirstName":"hihi","LastName":"0"},{"Site_ID":"10000004","FirstName":"","LastName":"0"},{"Site_ID":"10000005","FirstName":"SueAnn","LastName":"Hall"},{"Site_ID":"10000006","FirstName":"Test","LastName":"Name"}]
```

HTML with  script

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $.getJSON('checkin.php',function(data){
    $.each(data,function(name,value) 
    {
      items+="<option value='"+item.id+"'>"+item.name+"</option>";
    });
    $("#clients").html(items); 
  });
});
</script>

<select id="clients">
<option>Default</option>
</select>
</body>
```

Works fine until I run the html. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should define the `items` variable before concatenation.
2. `item` in your code is `undefined`, you should use `value` property that you have passed as the argument to the handler.
3. Your objects doesn't have `id` and `name` properties.

   ```
   var items = '';
   $.each(data,function(name,value) {
      items += "<option value='"+value.Site_ID+"'>"+value.FirstName+"</option>";
   });
   $("#clients").html(items);
   ```

http://jsfiddle.net/5PEPg/

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

1. You need to initialize items:

   var items = "";
2. You need to change the second parameter in your $.each() callback from `value` to `item`:

   ```
   $.each(data, function (name, item) {
       items += "<option value='" + item.id + "'>" + item.name + "</option>";
   });
   ```

This is assuming your collection is a list of objects containing an id and name property.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `value`.  You could also create and append each new `<option/>` in the `$.each` loop:

```
$(function(){
  $.getJSON('checkin.php',function(data){
    var lst = $("#clients").empty();
    $.each(data,function(index,value){
        $("<option/>").prop("value", value.Site_ID).text(value.FirstName + " " + value.LastName).appendTo(lst);
    });
  });
});​
```

Doing it this way will also prevent parsing issues with your `.html()` call with the concatenated string.  For example, if someone's first or last name had a double quote in it, the html would fail to parse.